# How to use a pop up?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I came across a js file which can do popup actions in magento.
Add this to local.xml

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>js</type>
        <name>prototype/window.js</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

And this to the template:

```
function showPopup(sUrl) {
    oPopup = new Window({
        id:'popup_window',
        className: 'magento',
        url: sUrl,
        width: 820,
        height: 600,
        minimizable: false,
        maximizable: false,
        showEffectOptions: {
            duration: 0.4
        },
        hideEffectOptions:{
            duration: 0.4
        },
        destroyOnClose: true
    });
    oPopup.setZIndex(100);
    oPopup.showCenter(true);
}

function closePopup() {
    Windows.close('popup_window');
}
//here assign click event to a tag with href to the content you want to display in popup
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('button selector')[0].observe('click', function(oEvent) {
         showPopup($(this).readAttribute('href'));
     Event.stop(oEvent);
   });
});
```

So when I click on `Click here to download STL file` link as shown in this screen shot,
[image: associatedfile]

then a pop up should open up and that pop up should contain this:
[image: stlviewer]

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a id="std" href="http://yourlink.com">Click here to download STL file</a>` where http://yourlink.com is the link to your STD viewer and std is the same selector as in

```
//here assign click event to a tag with href to the content you want to display in popup
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('std')[0].observe('click', function(oEvent) {
         showPopup($(this).readAttribute('href'));
     Event.stop(oEvent);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to read the documentation of this prototype library which you can find here: http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/

To answer your specific usecase, add this code and it will work:

```
oPopup.getContent().update("<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuChb.png'/>");
```